# Find the max number in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wrote some functions to find the maximum number of a list. If my list contains numbers and other types it gets only the numbers and finds the maximum, if my list is empty then it returns None. My only problem is that it always returns the number 7 instead of the 32 which is bigger than 7

```
#gets the numbers
def getint( l ):
    result=[]
    x=0
    if not l:
        print('The list is empty')
    else:
        while x!=len(l):
            if l[x].isdigit() == True:
                result.append(l[x])
            x += 1
    return result

#returns true or false
def all_ints( l ):
    result=[]
    x=0
    y=0
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i].isdigit() == True:
            continue
        else:
            y=1
    if(y==1):
        result.append(False)
    else:
        result.append(True)
    return result

#get the maximum
def max_int( l ):

    x=0
    if not l:
        max='none'
    else:
        max = l[0]
        while x!=len(l):
            if l[x] > max:
                max = l[x]
            x+=1

    return max

#return true or false if its empty
def isEmpty( l ):
    if not l:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check( l ):
    max=0
    val=isEmpty(l)
    if(val==True):
        max='None'
    elif(all_ints(l)==True):
        max=max_int(l)
    else:
        new_l=getint(l)
        max=max_int(new_l)
    return max


print(check(['4','5','6','7', '32']))
```

Comment: Where are you converting those strings to integers?

Comment: You are using text max (which is 7) instead of number max (which is 32). As christian asked, need to convert to number first

Comment: Tip: You could also use `max` function to get the maximum of the list in one line.

Comment: If there are numbers and letters in my list, will it work?

Comment: @john See my answer for the error check: I used try ... except statement. Pretty useful thing, btw.

Answer (score 0):

In your `max_int` function, you compare two strings instead of numbers. The problem is, that `32 > 7 == True`, but `'32' > '7' == False`. [More on comparing strings.](https://stackabuse.com/comparing-strings-using-python/)

Also, I would suggest that you just convert to integer and check for errors and then look for maximal number.

```py
def max_num(l):
    int_arr = []
    for i in l:
        try:
            int_arr.append(int(i))
        except:
            pass
    return max(int_arr)


print(max_num(['4','5','6','7', '32']))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are defining the numbers as characters, and in reality the first character is compared, if you put them as numbers really, your code will result in 32

Fix this

```
print(check(['4','5','6','7', '32']))
```

for

```
print(check([4,5,6,7,32]))
```